# What is and Where is the Community Wiki?

Tags: support, answers, community-wiki

In answering a question recently, I noticed the box to 'Add to Community Wiki'.

I didn't check the box, but I have been looking for a link to this mythical place and there doesn't seem to be one anywhere. Can someone explain what or where the Community Wiki is, is it specific to Joomla and how/why would we use it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This topic has been covered quite extensively over the years because the usage of this feature is often misunderstood across all Stack Exchange communities and sometimes used as workaround when a contributor feels that they generally shouldn't post anything at all (but they are overly compelled to help the OP).

In no particular order, here are some references:

- [What are "Community Wiki" posts?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/11740/352329)
- [What is the point of a stackoverflow community wiki?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/33428/352329)
- [What are the guidelines for community wiki on Meta Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/1320/352329)
- [Community Wiki, where is it?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/310947/2943403)
- [Why would you mark an answer as Community Wiki?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/343086/2943403)
- [When is it justified to Community Wiki your own answers?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/369182/2943403)
- [What really happens when I edit a Community Wiki post?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/321797/2943403)

If you don't have time to read all of that, **my personal opinion is that you should only tick the wiki box on your post if you know that you do not possess all of the necessary wisdom to provide a complete answer**.  This signals that you are actively encouraging edits from other community members to make your answer whole.  Beyond that, I find no compelling reason to use it.  If you never post a Wiki Answer -- that in no way reflects that you are under-utilising this community's features.

You can find all community wiki posts in a given Stack Exchange community by entering `wiki:1` into the community's search box.  On JSE, https://joomla.stackexchange.com/search?q=wiki%3A1 is currently showing just 11 Answer Wikis.

---

This is an opportunity to explain that [Tag Wikis](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/382297/2943403) are different from Answer Wikis. JSE would **really** benefit from members of our community sharpening up our tag descriptions.  There are many tags that have no descriptions or usage instructions.  It is a bit of an artform to make great suggested tag edits, but there are rep rewards in doing good work.  Visit a few of Stack Overflow's tags to see examples of high quality tag edits then blend that with your Joomla knowledge and help us with our tags!